# Take user to element after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `location.reload()` to refresh the page after an item is created:

```
pano.save(json, {
    success: function(pano) {
      $scope.panos.push(json)
      $scope.$digest()
      $('.modal').modal('hide')
      location.reload()
    },
    error: function(pano, error) {
      console.log('Failed to create new pano object, with error message: ' + error.message)
    }
  })
```

How can I do it so that the user is taken to a certain element AFTER refresh?

Comment: `location.reload()` in `angular` ? It looks horrible...

Comment: i guess this is not the right way to do it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: do you mean HTMLElement.focus()? if so look at the following doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: are you using a router? if ngRouter or UIRouter then you could simply go to the route for the new model or if it's a simple case of scrolling to the item in the same page then use simple named anchor links in your template for the item and link to that - but don't use location.reload()